# Ошибка отправки формы python (page expired)

Tags: python, requests

Возникла нужда решать капчу на одном сайте, а затем отправлять форму. Вот немного кода:

```
import requests

[Решение капчи и получение её токена в переменную capchaKey]
splitter = ', {"_token": "'
page = requests.get(pageurl)
token = page.text.split(splitter)[1].split('"')[0]
data = {
 "_token": token,
 "g-recaptcha-response": capchaKey
}
ret = requests.post(pageurl, data=data)
```

Код страницы, откуда я получаю токен, вот:

```
[...] function(e) {e.preventDefault();$.post('/capcha/', {"_token": "nfvTLlFa8Kd
QdFsJMTMQj5fBhMbvqnrvdV7RYCvk",'g-recaptcha-response': grecaptcha.getResponse()}
, function(data){if(data.success) {$("#msgBox").html(data.msg);} else {alert('Un
known error')}});return false;});})
```

Sitekey уже есть.
Вот так выглядит запрос с браузера (где все работает).
[image: Картинка]

Но всегда у меня возвращается ошибка 419 "Page Expired".

Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: data=data может быть как JSON

Comment: Он там и есть как JSON.

Comment: Так и отправляйте как Json, а не словарь.